# What kind of sensors to be used to measure the carbon dioxyde concentration?

Tags: gas

I'm planning a thought project for measuring the C02 in a room (at office namely), and communicating its results to a computer.

But I'm blocked at the early stage: which sort of sensor and which is the mechanism to measure the CO2 concentration in air ?

I saw devices for sale, not communicating with computers, only LCD screens, and there were no indications on what is the system/mechanism used.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used NDIR sensors, such as these:
http://www.alphasense.com/index.php/products/ndir-safety/

It's based on a light source which is flashed at a regular frequency and reflected on a series of mirrors before ending on a receiver. The sensor provides 2 signals: one "reference" signal, which remains constant regardless of the % of CO2, and one "active" signal which changes with the % of CO2 in the air. You have to calibrate the sensor with different % of CO2, and you can compensate for temperature and pressure variations.

Comment: Great starting Point. I found several references to start with.